# Laravel - Count options with hasMany in a Model

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following situation:

I have some questions and this questions has possible answers. I would like to count how many times were answered each item for each question.

For this I have 3 tables:

- Questions
- Answers
- Answers_questions

In the **Answers_questions** I have this relationship:

```
public function question(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Question', question_id, 'id');
}
```

and

```
public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Answers', 'question_id', 'question_id');
}
```

To retrieve this informations, in the Controller I use this:

```
$answers_questions = new Answers_questions;
$questions = $answers_questions->groupBy('question_id')->get();
```

In the view:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)

{{ $question->question }}

  @foreach($question->answer as $answer)
    Answer: {{ $answer->answer}} - **Count: ???**

  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

So, How can I count this to show in my view? I tryied this:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Answers', 'question_id', 'question_id')->selectRaw('*, count(answer) as count');
```

And after in the view for each question, just showed the first answer with the count.

How to solve?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try to do this for example:

```
public function countAnswers(){
    return count($this->hasMany('App\Answers', 'question_id', 'question_id'));
}
```

And on your redirect to view:

```
public function redirectToView(){
    $answers = countAnswers();
    return view('your.view.file' , compact('answers'));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but still count only the first answer.

Comment: you can try to implement the count method: 
$questions=$answers_questions->groupBy('question_id')->get()->count();

Comment: Thanks Vinicius. I'll try it and come back to tell if it worked.